# how to pick multiple images from gallery and store them in array in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

i used image_picker package in my app and it works fine for one image but now i want to use it for multiple images and store them in an array as File. any idea could be greate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add dependecy of image_picker:

```
       image_picker: ^0.8.4+3
```

Then make a method for selectImages():

```
      final ImagePicker imagePicker = ImagePicker();
      List<XFile>? imageFileList = [];

      void selectImages() async {
         final List<XFile>? selectedImages = await 
                imagePicker.pickMultiImage();
           if (selectedImages!.isNotEmpty) {
              imageFileList!.addAll(selectedImages);
           }
          print("Image List Length:" + imageFileList!.length.toString());
          setState((){});
      }
```

Create a builder for showing selected Images:

```
     return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Multiple Images'),
         ),
        body: SafeArea(
           child: Column(
             children: [
                 ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      selectImages();
                  },
                 child: Text('Select Images'),
               ),
               Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: GridView.builder(
                        itemCount: imageFileList!.length,
                       gridDelegate: 
                          SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                              crossAxisCount: 3),
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                           return Image.file(File(imageFileList![index].path), 
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,);
                     }),
                 ),
               ),
             ],
            ),
          ));
```

Complete Source code available in github link...

> > https://github.com/NishaJain24/multi_image_picker

Comment: The github link you shared is `multi_image_picker`, but your code use `image_picker`.

Comment: Its name of my project but i used the image_picker libarary for selecting multiple images. You can check i wrote image_picker here and in github link same library in pubspec.yaml file.

Answer (score 1):

you should use this

> ```
>  //add this to pubspec.yaml
>      multi_image_picker: ^4.7.14
> ```

```
  //add those to the dart file
     import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
     import 'package:multi_image_picker/multi_image_picker.dart';
     import 'dart:async';
```

> ```
>  //add a button then in onPressed do this
> MultiImagePicker.pickImages(
>         maxImages: 300,
>         enableCamera: true,
>         selectedAssets: images,
>         materialOptions: MaterialOptions(
>           actionBarTitle: "FlutterCorner.com",
>         ),
>       );
> ```

for further infos check this

https://medium.com/@fluttercorner/how-to-select-multiple-images-with-flutter-8fe8e4c78d08

Answer (score -2):

The documentation covers that in [here](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) .

```
final List<XFile>? images = await _picker.pickMultiImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
```

That saves it in a list of XFile. There are some platform specific implementation you have to go through so dont miss that. Just have a look at the documentation.

Comment: i use http and dio package and this package have conflict with their version

Comment: You can find a package version that is compatible with  all 3 packages by removing all 3 packages and doing a `pub add <package_name>`  on all packages but start with the file_picker package.

Alternatively you can use [file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) package and that is compatible with dio & http because i use that myself.
Here are the packages i use, hope it helps. 

    `file_picker: ^3.0.2+2`
    `dio: ^4.0.0`
    `http: ^0.13.2`

Use that and `FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(allowMultiple: true, type: FileType.image);`

Comment: The type has been set to image to it filters only the images out for you. Hope this can help